# (ssg-wsg) ScheduleInfoType code and descption; ScheduleInfo

Tags: api

1. I would like to seek clarification on what the Schedule Info Code and Description are. The API docs did not fully describe what these are. Examples given are not sufficient to help in understanding them.
2. Are the code and descr fields related to the ScheduleInfo field (e.g. Sat / 5 Sats / 9am-6pm)? The example given appears to be a concatenation/collection of info into 1 field. It does not look like it fits into "ScheduleInfo.descr" field.

Pardon me if i cannot make my questions clearer because the API doc's description of these fields are also rather hard to grasp.

Please help clarify.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the Course Run APIs (https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/docs/product/6kYpfJEWVb7NyYVVHvUmHi/group/374zmR5D0tQeS87eA1hrLV/api/5FkiXK236UniFUNSNHsmiI/version/6H7tGFfQQLYizvVs8Uziz1).

This is a Training Partner related API for the integration to Training Partners Gateway (TPG). You should be able to get more information at the following guides:

https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/articles/1UKSL2280Gpn9oDqCGECKT

https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/faq?anchor=WhereCanIFindTheFullListOfAPIsRequiredForIntegrationWithTheTpgateway

https://www.tpgateway.gov.sg/who-we-are/self-help-guides

https://www.tpgateway.gov.sg/faq/course-runs

https://www.tpgateway.gov.sg/docs/default-source/default-document-library/about-tpg/new-guides-(apr2021)/06-tgs_cm_course-runs-qrg.pdf?sfvrsn=6c88ce4b_4